# How to read emails/attachments automatically

Tags: email-attachments

My problem is two fold.
1. I have a customer base that need to send me attachments.  When they register with me, I'd like to assign them a unique email address.  ie. uniqueId@...com

Is there a "special" way to do this, or do I need a mail server?  I'm not really across mail servers other than how to set MX records.  So not sure how they really work.

2. The emails that they send me will have attachments.  PDFs, .doc, Images.  I want to automatically read the attachments using OCR technology.

More after a point in the right direction of how I would implement something like this.

Comment: You have a mail server? if so, use smtp and download the attachments and contents of email by the API provided and save the attachments.

Comment: Oh yea. You need a mail server.